# If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then there exist increasing simple functions $s_n \rightarrow f$ with $\mu(\{x:s_n \neq 0\})< \infty$

Tags: measure-theory

**Problem**

If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, $f$ non-negative and measurable, then there exist simple functions $s_n$ increasing to $f$ at each point such that $\mu(\{x:s_n \neq 0\})< \infty$ for each $n$.

**Background**

A measure $\mu$ on a space $X$ is $\sigma$-finite if there exists a sequence $(E_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of measurable sets with $X=\bigcup E_i$ and $\mu(E_i)<\infty$ for all $i$.

A simple function $s$ is a function of the form 
$$s(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\chi_{E_i}(x),$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $E_i$ are measurable sets.

**Claim 1** If $f$ is non-negative and measurable, then there exists a sequence of non-negative measurable simple functions $s_n$ increasing to $f$.

**proof** The following is a standard construction. Let $$E_{ni}=\{x:(i-1)/2^n\leq f(x)<i/2^n\}$$ and $$F_n=\{x:f(x)\geq n\}$$ for $n=1,2,...$ and $i=1,2,...,n2^n$. Then $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n2^n}\frac{i-1}{2^n}\chi_{E_ni}+n\chi_{F_n}$$ is the desired sequence.

**Attempt at Answering Question**

Let $X=\bigcup A_k$ with $\mu(A_k)<\infty$. Then for each $n$, $$X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(A_k\bigcap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n2^n} E_{in}\right)\right)\bigcup\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(A_k\bigcap F_n\right)\right).$$ Let $$E'_{in}=A_k\bigcap \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n2^n} E_{in}\right)$$ and $$F'_n=A_k\bigcap F_n$$ we see that $\mu(E'_{in}$ and $\mu(F'_n)$ are both finite and $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n2^n}\frac{i-1}{2^n}\chi_{E'_ni}+n\chi_{F'_n}$$ is a sequence of non-negative measurable step functions increasing to $f \ \ ^{(***)}$ and $\mu(\{x:s_n(x) \neq 0\}) < \infty$ for each $n$.

**My Question**

How can I justify $\ \ ^{(***)}$?

Comment: If you consider $R$ with Lesbegue measure $\lambda $ , then $\lambda $ is $\sigma $-finite and taking $s(x)=1$, you get $\lambda \left \{ x:s\neq 0 \right \}=\infty $ so maybe you want your measure to be finite? Or do you have some condition on $f$? Also are you sure your sets $E'_{im}$ and $F'_{n}$ are what you want?

Comment: In my book the only condition on $f$ is that it is non-negative and measurable

Comment: Not good to use the notation $E_i$ in several different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You can simplify the problem by writing $X = \cup E_n,$ where each $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ and $E_1\subset E_2 \subset \dots$

Comment: Could you give a bit more information? I see that in this case $\mu(E_n)\leq \mu(E_{n+1})$ but I do not know how to use your hint to construct the desired sequence.

Comment: Take the $s_n$ you mentioned and consider $t_n=s_n\chi_{E_n}.$